# Variable used in addEventListener callback is undefined

Tags: javascript

In the below case, how can i make the new value of `testvar` available in addEventListener callback function? In the below case, the value of `testvar` is undefined.

```
var testvar;
setTimeout(function(){
  var testvar = "testvar value"; 
 }, 3000);

document.querySelector('#anotherButton').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  console.log('testvar '+testvar);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local declaration of `testvar` is hiding the global declaration.

```js
var testvar = "Old value";
setTimeout(function(){
  // Here just reuse the global declaration.
  testvar = "testvar value";  
 }, 3000);

document.querySelector('#anotherButton').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  console.log('testvar: '+ testvar);
});
```

```html
<button id="anotherButton">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: this seems to work, but how come i get undefined when i use my code, whats the diff between this code snippet and mine?(I can seem to figure out the difference, sorry)

Comment: never mind figured it out, i am declaring `testvar` again in the setimeout function

Answer (score 2):

```
var testvar = ...
```

You just declared a new local variable.
It is completely unrelated to your other variable, which you never set.

Comment: its value is initialised in the setimeout function after 3 secs, how can i make the new variable value available in the addeventlistener callback when i click the button

Comment: remove the `var` ---> `testvar = "testvar value";`

Comment: @diabolicfreak: You need to set the existing variable, not declare a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `var` sign  inside the `setTimeout` method

```
var testvar;
setTimeout(function(){
  testvar = "testvar value"; 
 }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Declared variables are constrained in the execution context in which they are declared.

```
var testvar; // default value undefined
```

**testvar** variable is redeclared and its scope is now within that function

```
setTimeout(function(){
var testvar = "testvar value"; // testvar value and its scope is within this set
 }, 3000);
```

Hence outside setTimeout function , testVar variable value is **undefined**

To achieve expected , remove var and make it global testVar variable to return value - **"testvar value"**